# How to safe interpolate strings in slick

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have an sql query which can have different where clause. I want dynamically insert this clause into plain sql:

```
val v1 = s"id = $id AND secondId IS NULL"
val v2 = s"secondId = $secondId"

val whereCondition = //v1 or v2 at runtime   

val query = sql"select id from users where #$whereCondition"
```

As you can see it's not safe in case of sql injection. It there more safe way to build this sql?

Comment: I'd suggest not using plain-sql here if that's an option and dynamically build the query instead

Comment: I second that. Use slick's type-safe query instead of plain sql queries. Read: [Slick type-safe, composable queries](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/sql-to-slick.html#slick-type-safe-composable-queries). This way Slick would take care of SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a queryConcatenator trait which basically composes SQLAction together to dynamically create sql.

```
trait QueryConcatenator {
      def concatQuery(firstQuery: SQLActionBuilder, secondQuery: SQLActionBuilder): SQLActionBuilder = {
        SQLActionBuilder(
          firstQuery.queryParts ++ secondQuery.queryParts,
          new SetParameter[Unit] {
            override def apply(v1: Unit, v2: PositionedParameters): Unit = {
              firstQuery.unitPConv.apply(v1, v2)
              secondQuery.unitPConv.apply(v1, v2)
            }
          }
        )
      }
```

Your DbRepo then can extend the concatenator and you are on your way

```
    class DbRepo extends QueryConcatenator {
      def withDynamicFilter(maybeProductId:Option[Long]):Future[Vector[Product]] = {

      val baseStatement = Seq(sql"""select * from products""")
      val maybeFilter = if (maybeProductId.isEmpty) Seq(sql"") else Seq(sql" and productId = ${maybeProductId.get}")
      val concatenatedSql = baseStatement ++ maybeFilter
      val concatenatedActionBuilders =
        concatenatedSql.reduce((query1, query2) => concatQuery(query1, query2))

      db.run(concatenatedActionBuilders.as[Product])}
  }
```